# Javascript: compute total bytes transferred and total requests to render page?

Tags: javascript, performance, monitoring

I'd like to track the total bytes transferred, and total requests, to render a page in javascript. I want to collect these numbers from real users "in the wild" to use them for performance monitoring and reporting, so tools like YSlow or Chrome's dev tools aren't appropriate for this application.

Is there a "known good" way to collect this data in javascript? I realize there might be restrictions (for instance, any information about the data transferred by an iframe on a different domain will be opaque); I can live with that.

Comment: You've seen things like [YSlow](http://yslow.org/)?

Comment: The exact number of requests seems to be a tricky one. You can at least make use of the Navigation Timing API to determine the DOMLoaded, Loaded timing, although number of requests is still up for grabs. And, of course, in an isolated environment you can do the test using a browser's F12 Developer Tools. (This wouldn't let you measure the performance of random user Bob Smith though)

Comment: Several of the built-in browser dev tools have performance tools, including recent versions of IE, Firefox Dev Edition (not sure for other versions), and Chrome. YSlow as mentioned is available as a plugin as well, but even without it there's quite a bit there. The network tab in at least Chrome has a summary at the bottom with total requests and bytes transferred, as well as the breakdown by request in the main body of the panel. If you need to profile javascript, it's a rare case where I actually prefer IE11's tools, although Chrome/FF are capable as well.

Comment: Added clarification to the question: this is for "real world" monitoring, so it needs to happen in the actual script so I can submit the data (via eg. navigator.sendBeacon) to be collated on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the browser's [`Performance` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance) which was created to do exactly the things you're interested in.
Specifically, you will be able to get a [`PerformanceResourceTiming`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceResourceTiming) object for every fetched resource, which also includes the [number of transferred bytes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceResourceTiming/transferSize).

Comment: MDN marks these api's as deprecated, but doesn't link to any modern replacements

Comment: @Ferrybig I don't see any of the APIs I mentioned being marked as deprecated on MDN? What are you referring to specifically?

Comment: Following your first link to the [Performance API](Performance API) shows a thumbsdown icon after every property, and hovering it shows "This deprecated API should no longer be used, but will probably still work.". Then it shows 2 properties which aren't standardized yet

Comment: @Ferrybig But its methods are not, and those are [what should be used to get `PerformanceResourceTiming` entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Resource_Timing_API/Using_the_Resource_Timing_API).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trace the no of ajax request you can use ajaxStart ,but for other request image etc there is no proper api in JavaScript,you can use Browser extension to detect it but it is difficult for web application

Google is developing octane and some other performance tool available but it will not detect the no of request